# ways to create LightningMessageChannel in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I know we can create **LightningMessageChannel** using package.xml but is there any quick way to create it? Any UI alternative would be far better than package.xml route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `package.xml`, you can use `force:source:deploy` and `force:source:push` as well (Scratch Orgs only). But you *do* need an offline file to deploy your messages at the time of this writing.

Simply create the file in:

```
force-app/main/default/messageChannels/channelname.messageChannel-meta.xml
```

And then deploy it with:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u my-user-name -p force-app/main/default/messageChannels/channelname.messageChannel-meta.xml
```

You can also build an Unlocked Package to install it in various orgs, etc.

There have been discussions about a UI for this, but nothing concrete has been announced yet, so you may as well get used to it for now... or build your own...?

It's worth noting that LMC was designed to be used with LWC (and others), which also do not have a UI, so it's not entirely unexpected that LMC would also lack a UI.